# Facebook API - Paging - limit of 270 items?

Tags: python, facebook, json, api

I've been playing around with the Facebook API for a bit now, and I think I got it working quite well, however, when fetching my friends list I bump into a limit of 270 (271?) items returned with a **paging** key in the json data.

Naturally I try to iterate threw the **next** page in the **paging** key, however, the array returned from the next page is empty, it contains a **next** and **previous** key but no actual data, anyone know what's wrong?

Tried it straight in the browser just to ignore all programming errors and it's the same there as it is in the code:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&limit=5000
```

I've also tried with `&offset=269` etc, nothing really works, here's the output:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Person A",
         "id": "..."
      },
      {
         "name": "Person B",
         "id": "..."
      },
      {
         "name": "Person C",
         "id": "..."
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?limit=5000&offset=5268&value=1&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&__after_id=[Person C ID]",
      "previous": " Previous URL ... "
   }
}
```

When trying this URL in the browser (or via code), I get this:

```
{
   "data": [

   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?limit=5000&offset=268&value=1&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]"
   }
}
```

Why is this and how do you go about fixing it?

Appreciate all the help i can get, thank you!

Edit: I have 284 friends, so there should be 10+ on the "next" paging.

(Programming done in Python via the "Official Python SDK" (modified to handle paging)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's cos you might only have 270 (271) friends? Unless you are sure you have more friends...

If you have more than 270 friends. There could be two other reasons:

- Those 14 users have prevented apps from accessing their data via the API
- Facebook has cached your friend's list and you need to wait for the cache to be updated.

Comment: forgot to mention that (obvious?) detail, i have 284 friends, and i can't get the last 14 or so friends :/

Comment: OK. It could be that those 14 friends have prevented apps from accessing their data. Either that or Facebook have cached your friends list and you just need to wait until it refreshes...

Comment: In my experience it's the former that's more likely

Comment: OP: you can verify if the 'missing' friends have disabled platform by accessing `/FRIEND_USER_ID_HERE` in the Graph API and it'll return 'false' if they've disabled all platform apps

Comment: @Igy i'll check the /friend theory/idea, sounds like a simple task to test and logic says that it should give me an error if they don't like me programming up their alley so to speak :) bbl with an answer to the test (and FB cache refresh theory)

Comment: Ok so i've tested grap.facebook.com/<friend ID which is not showing up in the friends query> and from what i can tell it's working perfectly fine.

I'm getting data back and nothing stops me from querying the friend manually.

Note: I added this friend a while back (a month or so) and she doesn't show up in my /me/friends query, but a friend which i added yesterday is showing up in the /me/friends query.

Comment: And they're definitely a friend, and not appearing in your friends list because you sent them a friend request? that's odd

Comment: Yea i have no unanswered friend requests, and no pending requests either. Cache theory sounded logical but that's out of the question as well. And they're not blocking me. Also, the "next" page that you get a link to only appears if there's data to fetch in the graph API as far as i can tell, so there should be data there. File a bug report to Facebook about it? altho then more then i should have a problem with the API...